# Does a form "spiritum", second declension neuter, exist?

Tags: vocabulary

Today, as I browsed Quora, I saw a question with an (apparently) blatant case error. I opened it, and curiously, [one answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-the-Latin-phrase-Sum-Spiritum-Sanctum/answer/Aender-Dos-Santos-LaaendaerSan?share=cd9be552&srid=hIv7E) stated it could have been a correct case, since, while there is indeed "spiritus", fourth declension masculine, there is also a "spiritum", second declension neuter. Does such a word actually exist and, if so, does it mean "spirit" like "spiritus" or something else, and in the latter case, what does it mean?

Comment: It doesn't appear in Lewis & Short, at least, but it's hard to prove a negative.

Comment: Several dictionaries mention spiritum, -i n. *Itala act. 16.7* (versioni della Bibbia diverse dalla Vulgata)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Not in standard Classical Latin.

It's difficult to prove a negative, but Lewis and Short make no mention of it, and [the Packhum corpus](http://latin.packhum.org/search) shows no evidence of forms like *spīritī* or *spīritō*.

### However…

L&S cite an inscription, *Inscr. Orell. 3030*, which has a dative *spīritō* (instead of *spīrituī*). In the comments, Alex B cites a dictionary of later Latin with an entry for *spīritum, -ī*. So this form definitely existed, even if Cicero wouldn't have used it.

Comment: I was wondering if Italian _spirito_ (pl. -i) came from that form. As for Ecclesiastical Latin, I've never seen it

Comment: @Rafael The Italian nouns mostly come from Latin accusatives like *spiritum*, which would look like that in both second and fourth declension. The similarity to ablatives and datives is coincidental. See [this older question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5792/79).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta AFAIK, the mechanism is more or less the same as Spanish, but Spanish kept the -u (espíritu). It might be a 4th-declension thing or an archaism, though